Issue in generating pdf file when I run .exe
self.create_pdf = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text='Convert to PDF', variable=self.create_pdf).pack()


def convert_to_pdf(doc_name):
            pdf_name = doc_name.replace('.docx', '.pdf')
            convert(doc_name)
            print(f"PDF {pdf_name} created successfully.")


        
        doc_name = f"{outward_number.replace(' ', '_')}_information.docx"
        doc.save(doc_name)
        print(f"Document {doc_name} created successfully.")
        if self.create_pdf.get():
            convert_to_pdf(doc_name)

The above code works fine. But when I run it in .exe application. It says none object has no attribute value 'write'.
